# How to trigger a click on a select with Cypress?

Tags: cypress

By default it's not possible to trigger a click on a select element using cypress, and you will get a warning to use `.select()` instead:

```
cy.get('.myselect').click({ force: true });
```

*CypressError: cy.click() cannot be called on a  element. Use cy.select() command instead to change the value.*

In my case, clicking on a select triggers an api call to populate the select with a list of values, from which you can then select. So I cannot select anything until the options actually exist. Is there any way around this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since there is no way to for Cypress to open the select dropdown (its a native widget), Cypress errors.

However, you can still use `cy.get(...).trigger('click')` to send the event ([docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger.html#Syntax)).

> Note: you should listen to the `focus` event instead for accessibility reasons since users can also tab into a `select`. In that case you can use `cy.get(...).focus()`

Comment: That worked, thank you! And yes, you are right about the focus.